# Relation between number of tree edges in graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ components.

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

It's a sort of given in my book without any proof that :

> $$t=n-k$$
>   where,
>   $t$ = the number of **tree edges** 
>   $n$ = number of vertices 
>   $k$ = number of components.

Can someone explain me the theory behind this with a proof?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tree with one component and $n$ vertices, it has $n-1$ edges, correct? If there were more, we would have a cycle.

If you have a tree with $2$ components, that is really the same as your tree with one component with one more edge removed, so $n-2$ edges.

Continue this until you have $k$ components and you'll get the result.

Comment: I understood what your answer but I'm unable to use it in the solution to this problem.
In a depth-first traversal of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, $k$ edges are marked as tree edges. The number of connected components in $G$ is?
The answer is $n-k$, How? I don't understand!

Comment: @Sidsec9 That's a separate question. You should make a new question to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that the number of nodes in each of the $k$ components be $a_1$, $a_2$,...,$a_k$. The dfs-trees for each of these components will have exactly $a_1-1$, $a_2-1$,....$a_k-1$ tree edges each.Now summing these tree edges we get,
$a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_k-(1+1+....k \ \text{times})$. Now we know that $a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_k=n$. Therefore, we get number of tree edges equal to $n-k$.